Low Accuracy on MNIST Dataset by CNN model built using GNN Bundles
I am working on a project using ECL and GNN bundles to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) on the MNIST dataset. The model architecture includes three convolutional layers with batch normalization and ReLU activation, followed by max-pooling layers, and ending with three dense layers. Despite normalizing and reshaping the data correctly and using categorical cross-entropy as the loss function with the Adam optimizer, I am observing very low accuracy on the test set. The training accuracy does not improve significantly beyond a certain point. I have implemented the model architecture and data preprocessing steps correctly. Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to improve the model's accuracy would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the ECL attached:
IMPORT Python3 AS Python;
IMPORT GNN.Tensor;
IMPORT GNN.Internal.Types AS iTypes;
IMPORT GNN.Types;
IMPORT GNN.GNNI;
IMPORT GNN.Internal AS Int;
IMPORT STD;

kString := iTypes.kString;
kStrType := iTypes.kStrType;
t_Tensor := Tensor.R4.t_Tensor;
TensData := Tensor.R4.TensData;

// Test parameters
batchSize := 32;
numEpochs := 250;
trainToLoss := .0001;
bsr := .25; // BatchSizeReduction.  1 = no reduction.  .25 = reduction to 25% of original.
lrr := 0.01;  // Learning Rate Reduction.  1 = no reduction.  .1 = reduction to 10 percent of original.

// Get training data
SET OF REAL4 get_train_X() := EMBED(Python)

  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  
  (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  
  # Normalize the pixel values to be between 0 and 1
  x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.0
  
  # Reshape to add the channel dimension
  x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
  return x_train.flatten().tolist()
  
ENDEMBED;

SET OF REAL4 get_train_Y() := EMBED(Python)

  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

  # Convert labels to one-hot encoding
  y_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train,10)
  return y_one_hot.flatten().tolist()
ENDEMBED;

train_X := get_train_X();
train_Y := get_train_Y();


t1Rec := RECORD
  REAL4 value;
END;

intpuRec := RECORD
  UNSIGNED8 id;
  REAL4 value;
END;

x1 := DATASET(train_X, t1Rec);
y1 := DATASET(train_Y, t1Rec);
x2 := PROJECT(x1, TRANSFORM(intpuRec, SELF.id := COUNTER - 1, SELF.value := LEFT.value));
y2 := PROJECT(y1, TRANSFORM(intpuRec, SELF.id := COUNTER - 1, SELF.value := LEFT.value));


x3 := PROJECT(x2, TRANSFORM(TensData, 
    SELF.indexes := [TRUNCATE(LEFT.id/784) + 1, TRUNCATE(LEFT.id%784/28) + 1, LEFT.id%28 + 1], 
    SELF.value := LEFT.value));
y3 := PROJECT(y2, TRANSFORM(TensData, 
    SELF.indexes := [TRUNCATE(LEFT.id/10) + 1, LEFT.id%10 + 1], 
    SELF.value := LEFT.value));


x := Tensor.R4.MakeTensor([0,28,28], x3);
y := Tensor.R4.MakeTensor([0, 10], y3);

// Define model
ldef := [
    '''layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28, 28, 1))''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))''',
    '''layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))''',
    '''layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3))''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.Flatten()''',
    '''layers.Dense(256)''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.Dense(128)''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.Dense(64)''',
    '''layers.BatchNormalization()''',
    '''layers.Activation('relu')''',
    '''layers.Dense(10)''',
    '''layers.Activation('softmax')'''
];

compileDef := '''compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), 
                loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
              ''';

s := GNNI.GetSession(0);  // Ensure this line uses the CPU
mod := GNNI.DefineModel(s, ldef, compileDef);

// Train model
mod2 := GNNI.Fit(mod, x, y, batchSize := batchSize, numEpochs := numEpochs,
                      trainToLoss := trainToLoss, learningRateReduction := lrr,
                      batchSizeReduction := bsr);
losses := GNNI.GetLoss(mod2);

// Evaluate this model
SET OF REAL4 get_test_X() := EMBED(Python)
  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  
  # Normalize the pixel values to be between 0 and 1
  x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
  
  # Reshape to add the channel dimension
  x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
  
  return x_test.flatten().tolist()
ENDEMBED;


SET OF REAL4 get_test_Y() := EMBED(Python)
  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

  # Convert labels to one-hot encoding
  y_one_hot = to_categorical(y_test,10)
  
  return y_one_hot.flatten().tolist()
ENDEMBED;


test_X := get_test_X();
test_Y := get_test_Y();

x1_test := DATASET(test_X, t1Rec);
y1_test := DATASET(test_Y, t1Rec);
x2_test := PROJECT(x1_test, TRANSFORM(intpuRec, SELF.id := COUNTER - 1, SELF.value := LEFT.value));
y2_test := PROJECT(y1_test, TRANSFORM(intpuRec, SELF.id := COUNTER - 1, SELF.value := LEFT.value));

x3_test := PROJECT(x2_test, TRANSFORM(TensData, 
    SELF.indexes := [TRUNCATE(LEFT.id/784) + 1, TRUNCATE(LEFT.id%784/28) + 1, LEFT.id%28 + 1], 
    SELF.value := LEFT.value));
y3_test := PROJECT(y2_test, TRANSFORM(TensData, 
    SELF.indexes := [TRUNCATE(LEFT.id/10) + 1, LEFT.id%10 + 1], 
    SELF.value := LEFT.value));

x_test := Tensor.R4.MakeTensor([0,28,28], x3_test);
y_test := Tensor.R4.MakeTensor([0, 10], y3_test);

metrics := GNNI.EvaluateMod(mod2, x_test, y_test);
preds := GNNI.Predict(mod2, x_test);
// GetWeights returns the initialized weights that have been synchronized across all nodes.
wts := GNNI.GetWeights(mod);

// OUTPUT results
ORDERED([OUTPUT(STD.Date.CurrentTime(TRUE), NAMED('startTime')), 
  OUTPUT(mod2, NAMED('mod2')),
  OUTPUT(STD.Date.CurrentTime(TRUE), NAMED('endTime')),
  OUTPUT(losses, NAMED('losses')),
  OUTPUT(metrics, NAMED('metrics')),
  OUTPUT(preds, NAMED('preds'))]);
  OUTPUT(wts, NAMED('InitWeights'));

OUTPUT(IF(metrics[2].value>0.95, 'Pass', 'Fail'), NAMED('CategoricalAccuracy'));


I tried different learning rates, batch sizes, and number of epochs, but none of these changes significantly improved accuracy. I expected the model to perform well on the MNIST dataset, achieving an accuracy similar to that of other standard CNN models trained on this dataset. Additionally, I verified that the model architecture and data preprocessing steps were implemented correctly.

If other models are giving you better accuracy I would have to look at the data itself. Also, when accuracy is in doubt you need to run the pure python equivalent with tensorflow to compare accuracy results. From a glance your code looks great but we will examine it further and reply back if we spot anything.
Regards,
Bob

Testing your code I was able to get better accuracy and result by adjusting the following:
batchSize := 5000;//32;
numEpochs := 5;//250;
trainToLoss := .0001;
bsr := .25; // BatchSizeReduction.  1 = no reduction.  .25 = reduction to 25% of original.
lrr := 1.0;//0.01;  // 1 = No Learning Rate Reduction. 


I did test the code again with the updated hyperparameters, getting an accuracy of just 9.2 %

The only thing I can see is that bsr and lrr should be 1 or very close to 1.  The batch size and learning rate would disappear with .25 or .01.

Then what else might be possibly going wrong? the python equivalent is giving me a good 99 percent accuracy.

Then what else might be possibly going wrong? the python equivalent is giving me a good 99 percent accuracy.

Please verify that your Python test reflects the same parameters and settings as the ECL version. 1. The training dataset is identical. 2. The parameters and definitions match. If you are absolutely certain of those two items than you need to open a Jira issue as soon as possible, attaching the python and ECL code in the report.

Link to the Issue Tracking System: Issue Tracking Page
Please attach your python example code and your ECL example code to your report.
